# ASP.net Webservice to return boolean value to Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

Here is my issue. I have a stored procedure that returns an output that is a bit. I am trying to view the Boolean value via the web service. The stored procedure totally works, but I can't seem to figure out how to display the needed value (which is a boolean).

The store procedure:

```
@CE_IN VARCHAR(2)
@return_OUT BIT OUTPUT
IF EXISTS(SELECT Ce FROM Table A WHERE @CE_IN = Ce)
BEGIN IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Table A)
set @return_OUT = 1
ELSE 
set @return_OUT = 1
END
ELSE set @return_OUT = 0
```

The following library class is what I use to call the stored procedure.

```
public Boolean ValidC(String VC) 
    {
            DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand(spName);

            db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "CE_IN", DbType.String, VC);
            db.AddOutParameter(dbCommand, "return_OUT", DbType.Boolean, 1);
            db.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand);

            return (Boolean)dbCommand.Parameters["@return_OUT"].Value;
    }
```

Once executed the procedure returns the Boolean value. (In theory)

Last piece of the puzzle is the web service call.

```
[WebMethod]
public bool Validation(string VC)
     {
         ValidC c = new ValidC(VC);
         if(c. == true)
             return true;

         else
             return false;

     }
```

Comment: You can't figure out "how to make get the to the be server browser." That is the most word-salady thing I've seen in a SO question in a long time... p.s. J. Ballard? The guy from B613?

Comment: Correction. I can't figure out how to get the value to the web server. My mistake.

Comment: "but I can't seem to figure out how to display the needed value"...How are you trying to display it? Client side, in the browser I assume? How does your client-side look like?

Comment: RealityDysfunction on the client side I would like to display it as a JSON. The stored procedure executes and gives me the 1 or a 0 bit in MSSQL. Code that calls the stored procedure gets the parameter but the web service method doen't work correctly.

Comment: Ilya Nemtsev is actually right. You can use the following site as a reference for doing so.
http://brian.dobberteen.com/code/jquery_ajax_custom_validator/

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is using jQuery on the client side.

```
sendData = new Object();
sendData.validateThis = "SomeDataToValidateGoesHere";
    $.ajax({
            url: "urlOfWebMethodOrSomething/ValidateField",
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(sendData),
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (resultObj) {
                      if (resultObj.valid == true) 
                          console.log("Yay I'm valid");
                      else
                          console.log("This sucks!");
                            },
            error: function () {
                      console.log('An error has occured...');
                            }
                        });
```

On server-side you can use a model like this...

```
public class ValidateResponse
{
    public bool valid { get; set; }
    public String ResponseMsg { get; set; }
}
```

Then respond in the WebMethod like so:

```
    public virtual String ValidateField(String validateThis)
    {
    ValidateResponse valResp = SomeValidationMethod(validateThis);
    return Json(valResp);
    }
```

Hope that gets you started...

Comment: I hope so too, Thanks. I'm going to see what I can get done with what you have up.